Handling broker restarts as publisher/producer without losing messages
While testing whether quorum queues work well with our existing infrastructure, I noticed that our current setup is not as resilient against broker failures / restarts as I had previously assumed (NB: The problem also happens with mirrored classic queues, I verified that after noticing the problem).
For context: We are using the bitnami chart for our RabbitMQ deployment (see: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq), with three replicas. We opted for a Service of type LoadBalancer, so that external connections to the broker are possible. This means my application uses spring.rabbitmq.addresses=<LOADBALANCER IP>.
Now, when the broker is restarted (e.g. by issuing kubectl rollout restart statefulset/rabbitmq, or by draining nodes for maintenance) and my application is connected to one of the restarting pods while publishing messages, I observed some rather unexpected behavior: Depending on different factors I am losing up to 20,000 messages out of a million. I then, of course, tried to understand the problem and find solutions to it, but I feel quite stuck at the moment.
What I really want:
On temporary broker connection errors, like they are happening when restarting, I want to make sure all my messages are delivered to the broker after the connection is restored.
If that is not possible I would want to get a log message for each message that could not be delivered.
For reference I built a small project to reproduce my "current" problem, you can find it at https://github.com/Linus9000/spring-amqp-demo/tree/master
Now, what did I actually find and learn?
First: My code publishing a message looked something like this:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@CommonsLog
public class RabbitController {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


    public RabbitController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {

        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> index() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            try {
                this.sendMessage("myexchange", "myrouting", String.valueOf(i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Could not send message", e);
            }
        }

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }


    private void sendMessage(String exchange, String routingKey, Object content) {

        MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
        properties.setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        Message message = new Message(content.toString().getBytes(), properties);

        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, message);
    }

}

Now, when I restart the broker while I am in the for loop (i.e. waiting for my controller call to finish) I get one(!) error log:
2024-06-18T09:15:30.370+02:00 ERROR 25988 --- [rabbitmq-demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.rabbitmqdemo.RabbitController  : Could not send message

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer

But when I check the broker (via management UI) I see only 959,372 messages in my queue. WTF happened here?
Naturally, this concerns me. After some digging I find the spring.rabbitmq.template.retry configs, leading to:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    template:
      retry:
        enabled: true
        max-attempts: 100
        multiplier: 2
        max-interval: 120000

Do note the quite absurd values here.
Unfortunately, this only leads to missing more messages, I'm down to 909,813 messages which actually make it into the queue.
So, next experiment. How about spring.rabbitmq.template.mandatory?
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    template:
      mandatory: true
      retry:
        enabled: true
        max-attempts: 100
        multiplier: 2
        max-interval: 120000

Still, only 947,848 messages.
Okay then, time for the next experiment: spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated. Due to performance penalties I now only try to put 150,000 messages into the queue:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    publisher-confirm-type: correlated
    template:
      mandatory: true
      retry:
        enabled: true
        max-attempts: 100
        multiplier: 2
        max-interval: 120000

Now we're getting somewhere: 149,970 messages in the queue. Only 30 messages missing! Time for the last puzzle piece, spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    publisher-confirm-type: correlated
    publisher-returns: true
    template:
      mandatory: true
      retry:
        enabled: true
        max-attempts: 100
        multiplier: 2
        max-interval: 120000

Now, we get additional error logs:
2024-06-18T09:39:53.980+02:00 ERROR 22904 --- [rabbitmq-demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Could not configure the channel to receive publisher confirms
java.io.IOException: null
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

And also:
2024-06-18T09:39:54.198+02:00 ERROR 22904 --- [rabbitmq-demo] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.rabbitmqdemo.RabbitController  : Could not send message

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: PublisherCallbackChannel is closed

And still, only 149,972 messages.
Maybe me catching the exception when sending is wrong? Maybe the retry config already handles that?
Let's try!
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> index() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 150_000; i++) {
            this.sendMessage("myexchange", "myrouting", String.valueOf(i));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

Now it just stops after getting disconnected once, which in this case means only 30,524 messages made it into the queue.
What possibilities do I even have left now?

Was able to reproduce locally against Testcontainers. No any exceptions are thrown back to the application: retry does the trick. But some messages are still lost even without quorum and delay exchange. Might be better to ask such a question up to RabbitMQ user group: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users

I did that: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/g_1VaiVQPsE

We haven't gotten to anything regarding spring-amqp (so far). While the code suggestions I got there are helpful for using the official client, I'd still need to reimplement all the retry logic, if I wanted it to be usable.
My further experiments with spring-amqp at least showed that setChannelTransacted(true) on the RabbitTemplate seems to work fine, but it's quite slow. This is expected per the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/template.html#publishing-is-async), but I still can't see an alternative approach..

I have since updated the demo project with a clearer README, and also added receiving messages to verify which messages exactly were sent and received successfully. I also tried adding some CorrelationData to the messages, and added a ReturnsCallback.
I still lose messages. When sending against our cluster some messaged are received multiple times, while I could not get that to happen with my single container. But that's besides the point for my main problem :-)
Do you think it would be worth it to raise an issue against spring-amqp for this?

Were you able to extract exact problem from Spring AMQP perspective? If you got same failure with plain AMQP Java Client, then I don't see how Spring could help. I'm not about pushing you away and would like to help, but my knowledge of RabbitMQ internals is zero. Maximum I can help from Spring perspective, but I need more info to determine where exactly Spring AMQP is wrong. Thanks for understanding!

Hi, I could not reproduce it with the official client, at least with the code that
Arnaud has provided (https://gist.github.com/acogoluegnes/c37292727701bf65d174fdef54a20872).
But given that his code does its thing asynchronously and Spring AMQP doesn't (speaking from my simple user perspective) I'm not sure what to make of it. I don't understand Spring AMQP enough, frankly. I'd assume it buffers my messages internally and will try to resend them, when the connection comes back. But where the publisherConfirmType comes into play and what it does exactly eludes me so far..

The RabbitTemplate does the same channel.basicPublish() and there is no buffering in RabbitTemplate.
